# Выбрать данные из javascript через get

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте ! Есть такой код:

```
$.get("http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AWP%20%7C%20Asiimov%20%28Field-Tested%29", function(data) {

    var gl = $(".market_listing_row:first", data),
        f = gl.attr("id").substring(8);


                $('#w').html(f);


}, 'html');
```

И есть страница (страница - посторонний сайт), на которой в тегах script находится код. Вот нужный мне кусок:

`<script type="text/javascript">`

```
var g_rgListingInfo = {
        "1467397635141908033": {
            "listingid": "1467397635141908033",
            "price": 0,
            "fee": 0,
            "publisher_fee_app": 730,
            "publisher_fee_percent": "0.10000000149011612",
            "currencyid": "2005",
            "asset": {
                "currency": 0,
                "appid": 730,
                "contextid": "2",
                "id": "3006960660",
                "amount": "0",
                "market_actions": [{
                    "link": "steam:\/\/rungame\/730\/76561202255233023\/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D11848599399387286495",
                    "name": "\u041e\u0441\u043c\u043e\u0442\u0440\u0435\u0442\u044c \u0432 \u0438\u0433\u0440\u0435\u2026"
                }]
            }
        },
        "343749525200261960": {
            "listingid": "343749525200261960",
            "price": 0,
            "fee": 0,
            "publisher_fee_app": 730,
            "publisher_fee_percent": "0.10000000149011612",
            "currencyid": "2003",
            "asset": {
                "currency": 0,
                "appid": 730,
                "contextid": "2",
                "id": "2950889167",
                "amount": "0",
                "market_actions": [{
                    "link": "steam:\/\/rungame\/730\/76561202255233023\/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D1057902019518049713",
                    "name": "\u041e\u0441\u043c\u043e\u0442\u0440\u0435\u0442\u044c \u0432 \u0438\u0433\u0440\u0435\u2026"
                }]
            }
        }
}
```

`</script>`

В переменной `f` у меня хранится число, которое соответствует числу `123` и `456`;

Вопрос в том, как получить эти данные ?

Пробовал делать так:

```
var b = g_rgListingInfo[f];
alert(b.price);
```

но к сожалению - безуспешно.

Ерорит именно строку `var b = g_rgListingInfo[f];`, как я понимаю оно не знает где искать переменную `a` или же формат, который возвращает `jQuery.get();` не подходит.

Как быть ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var match = data.match(/var g_rgListingInfo = {(.*?)},/);
```

Нужно было использовать регулярное выражение.

Answer (score 0):

А вы проверяли значение, которое присваиваете переменной `f`? Потому, как всё работает нормально.

```js
var a = {
    "123": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2,
        "mas": {
            "c": 3,
            "d": 4
        }
     },

     "456": {
         "a": 5,
         "b": 6,
         "mas": {
            "c": 7,
            "d": 8
          }
     }
};
var f = 123;
var b = a[f];
alert(b.a);
// или просто
// alert(a[f].a);
```

Comment: Может это потому что я получаю код сайта в html ? Я же получаю его через $.get.

Comment: @SlavikOkara, какой именно код: тот что приходит в ответе на ajax-запрос или oбъект `a`?  Если первое, то убедитесь, что существует элемент с классом "class_name", у этого элемента есть атрибут id и значение у этого атрибута побольше 8-ми символом. Если же второй вариант, то данные, как я понимаю, вы получаете в json-формате, который нужно преобразовать в объект: `var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);`

Comment: Я же дал точный пример. `}, "html");`, откуда вы взяли json ? Код тот что приходит в ответ на запрос. id есть и нормально парсится.

Comment: Вы бы лучше привели пример, что в *data* находится. Сразу станет понятно, почему не работает.

Comment: @SlavikOkara, я ничего и нигде не беру, а предполагаю разные варианты. Во-вторых, я вам сразу предложил проверить значение переменной `f`. (например, вывести в консоль). И в-третьих, как советует @zhenyab, покажите данные, которые приходят в ответе на запрос, а то будем еще долго гадать.

Comment: @zhenyab `data` выводит полностью весь html код страницы.

Comment: @SlavikOkara, посмотрите [этот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/xLkbsc7t/), может натолкнет вас на мысли.

Comment: @Deonis Вы так и не поняли. Переменная `a` тоже в data. Она хранится на странице, там же где и `div`!!!

Comment: @Deonis Я обновил код, посмотрите.